# Flash failing to fire any Events on URLLoader sometimes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an instance of URLLoader that works perfectly on my machine and a number of other machines, but in a few rare cases, regardless of the browser or the flash player version, URLLoader never comes back with any of my callbacks and so the load() method is fired off into the stratosphere and nothing happens beyond that.

Curious if anyone else has encountered this and if so how they got around it.

[EDIT]

Ok... never mind on the "no callbacks are fired". In fact it is firing the SecurityError.SECURITY_ERROR.  However, I'm at a total loss as to why it would only fire this on some machines and not on others.  Does it have something to do with the user's admin privileges or the browser's security settings? The error is 2170, phaseTwo (whatever that means)

[EDIT 2]

EUREKA!!! To www or not to www that is the question (or rather the answer).  The issue had nothing to do with computers, but rather with the page being loaded without the www in some instances. Flash doesn't know what to do in that situation. Brilliant!

Comment: Flash has its quirks, but in this case, I'd say it does know what to do: throwing a SecurityError. Sometimes, you know, it actually pays off to RTFM: http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html. Money quote: "Data loading is not allowed if the calling file is in the local-with-file-system sandbox and the target resource is from a network sandbox. Data loading is also not allowed if the calling file is from a network sandbox and the target resource is local."

Comment: ok, as long as we're RTFMing you may want to link to the 10.0 docs in which they have tightened security even further and, as sberry2A notes, have made it that the code also has to be initiated via user action such as a mouse click or a key press. In any event, I think it's a bit odd to RTFM at such a hidden and easy to miss aspect of the language.  Obviously once I came across that error the rest was simple, but it's pretty well hidden!

Comment: Firstly, I just quickly googled for the link and pasted it here as a courtesy, if you will. Let me remind you, though, I'm not the one with the problem. So that doesn't prevent you from taking a look at the very latest version of TFM. Secondly, I'd like to point out that URLLoaders don't need to be initiated by user actions. Not in FP9, nor in FP10. They can be initiated programatically. Please refer to TFM for further clarifications.

Comment: (cont...) Thirdly, I don't think this is hidden in any sense of the word. It's right there in the manual page that documents the class you're trying to use, and it's quite visible. I acknowledge this is easy to miss when you're trying to code something and just get it to work, though. I've done that myself, many times. And many times, after finding the problem, I found out that had I taken the time to actually read the docs I could have saved myself some time and hair pulling. That's why I mentioned TFM in the first place.

Comment: @Juan Pablo. I hear you. My point is that once I found the SecurityError, the rest did, indeed, take me a few minutes.  This post was actually edited 3 times as I got closer and closer to what was eventually the problem. However, when I started "TM" would have included pretty much T WHOLE FM. I wasn't being lazy, I just didn't know where to even start looking as the URLLoader appeared to simply not fire any of its events at all. Granted, I wasn't checking the SecurityError, but it seemed far fetched since it was working in all but a few instances (and I hadn't noticed the www discrepancy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things come to mind that could cause this:

Make sure you are catching `SecurityError.SECURITY_ERROR` and `IOError.IO_ERROR`. If an error occurs, the `COMPLETE` event won't be raised.

If `Loader` is not added to the UI-tree, it won't work. If that's the case, you should be using `URLLoader` instead.

If you are adding the event listeners using `addEventListener`, make sure you are not using weak references. If you are, and aren't rooted, they could be garbage collected which would cause your symptoms.

Comment: @Richard Szalay. "If URLLoader is not added to the UI-tree, it won't work". What do you mean by that?

Comment: It IS the SecurityError.SECURITY_ERROR!! Ok... but WTF?! Why is it only firing on some machines? What is that error connected to? (thanks a million for pointing me at it, I would never have thought to go catching it).

Comment: @Dr.Dredel - Are you calling back to the same server, or are you calling back to a hardcoded server? If they are not the same, you'll need a `crossdomain.xml`. That includes the case where the user is accessing the site with a slightly different domain name (like without `www.`)

Comment: @Juan - If you create a URLLoader in actionscript and call load without adding the URLLoader as a child to another display object on the stage, the URLLoader will never fire any events.

Comment: @Richard Szalay. I disagree. I think perhaps you are confusing Loader and URLLoader (not sure if your assertion applies to Loaders; I don't think so either, but haven't tryed it). URLLoaders can't be added as children to other display object containers. Anyway, if I understood you right, you say the following shouldn't work. But it works:

Comment: (cont)  `public class StaticLoader 
 {
  public static function load():void {
   var ld:StaticLoader = new StaticLoader();
   ld.loadFile();
  }
  public function loadFile():void {
   var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void { trace("complete")});
   loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:Event):void { trace("error")});
   loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, function(e:Event):void { trace("error")});
   loader.load(new URLRequest("http://s.ytimg.com/crossdomain.xml"));
  }
 }`

Comment: If you call this in this way `StaticLoader.load();`, you'll see the loader fires the events. I don't think one could say this loader has been added to the display list.

Comment: @Juan Pablo Califano - Apologies, I was confusing URLLoader and Loader. The added-to-stage requirement applies to `Loader`, not `URLLoader`

Comment: @Richard Szalay. No problem. I wasn't aware that Loaders had to be added to the stage to fire any events, so thanks for pointing it out. You learn something new every day!

Comment: I'm having this same issue, listening for every known event that URLLoader dispatches, and it's not doing anything when I call load.  Nothing.  The strange thing is, I am loading remote data into a local sandbox, and it worked once then failed, then worked again, and now it's just not working.  It's very strange.  Meanwhile, the method is used to load a resource right beforehand (remote into local) and it always works.  It's like after it loads one resource this way, it can't load any more, except that one instance where it mysteriously succeeded.  Sounds like a player bug or memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code, from what you describe it seems that your loader could be collected before it fires any events. If your loader is stored in a local variable, try to move to a class instance variable (and perhaps seeing some code could help).

The above problem (which may or may not be the problem here) is not common in practice, in my experience, but it's definitely possible (I've seen this myself). I'm not sure under what exact circumstances it happens. I *think* an active loader will not be collected. But I'm not sure an active loader for the player is the same as an active loader from an Actionscript perspective. Meaning, from you AS code, an active loader would be a loader on which you have invoked the load method and has not yet finished loading (with or without errors). Now, for the player (again, this is a -hopefully educated- guess), active could mean something different. You can download only 2 assets from one domain simultaneously (a browser restriction); if you try to load more stuff, these operations are queued by the player. So maybe, a loader on which you have called load but has not actually begun the real loading, is not considered active by the player and so it's collectable.

Comment: FYI, this scenario can't actually happen. Calling `load` on Loader / URLLoader roots them into the object graph. It's much more likely that weak references event handlers will be collected.

Comment: @Richard Szalay. I thought it couldn't happend, too. Until it happened to me. I only saw this in a case where I was running a bunch of loaders (and it only happened sometimes, if the GC happened to run). But if you have any links that prove the opposite I'd love to see them. The above is a guess as to *why* it happened, but it did happen to me and it wasn't weakref listeners (I never use them anyway).

Comment: This is also easy to reproduce with FileReference objects (which is a different object, I know but is also part of the networking API). To my knowledge, the only objects that are not collectable even if they don't have AS references are *running* Timers.